# Principal is returned as UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm experiencing what I think might be a bug.

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security. Normaly everything is running well but when I try to get the principal via the `HttpServletRequest` or directly from the controller it is cast to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` for some strange reason. When I use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` it returns the correct object.

Please see code below, please see the comments in the last 6 or so lines as to what is actual being returned.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ElementDto postElement(@RequestBody @Valid ElementDto element, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Principal principal) {
    logger.info("postElement - {}", element);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new SpringBootCommonError(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage(), SpringBootCommonErrorEnum.VALIDATION);
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)principal; /*is of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken*/
    Principal requestPrincipal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();/*is of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken*/
    Principal principalFromCast = (Principal)usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();/*is of type User (what I want)*/
    Object securityPrincipal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();/*is of type (what I want)*/
    element.setUploadedBy(((User) httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()).getEntityNo());
    return elementService.createElement(element);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`** is an implementation of interface **`Authentication`** which extends the interface `Principal`. `Principal` is defined in the JSE `java.security`. `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is a concept in Spring Security which implements the `Principal` interface.

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is basically a principal.

```java
    /**
     * The identity of the principal being authenticated. In the case of an authentication
     * request with username and password, this would be the username. Callers are
     * expected to populate the principal for an authentication request.
     * <p>
     * The <tt>AuthenticationManager</tt> implementation will often return an
     * <tt>Authentication</tt> containing richer information as the principal for use by
     * the application. Many of the authentication providers will create a
     * {@code UserDetails} object as the principal.
     *
     * @return the <code>Principal</code> being authenticated or the authenticated
     * principal after authentication.
     */
    Object getPrincipal();
```

This is the javadoc for the `getPrincipal()` method in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

So I would assume what you actually want is a **`UserDetails`** not a principal.

Comment: I understand the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken my issue is why is my Principal being returned as UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken for instance the following code works
`((User) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal()).getEntityNo()` but this code does not `((User) principal).getEntityNo()`
I dont' think I should have to cast it to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken then back to principal if it was originally principal

Comment: It is not so clear, which `principal` you are referring to in your comment. That depends on how the authentication provider implement it. Both HttpServeletRequest and SecurityContext should return you the right principal which is the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Answer (score -1):

If you have not configured explicitly, how you want to authenticate your user then, Spring Security by default uses

```
DaoAuthenticationProvider
```

for authentication  which uses

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

for Authenticating your user, if You are using UserName and Password to Authenticate your User.

That's the reason why, when your are trying to get the

```
Principal object
```

you need to typecast explicitly to

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

NOTE: Spring Security provides many other Authentication mechanism as well, say X.509,LDAP and even you can use JDBC Authentication as well.